# JQuery UI Slide pushes elements down, other solutions don't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**EDIT: Whoops I forgot to have the console open to clear the cache when working on my actual project. Previous solutions and the ones you suggested work just fine. Thanks guys**

So I'm trying to have something slide out while something else inline stays stationary. However, the sliding pushes other elements below downwards.

Here is the basic HTML:

```
<div id="title-container">
  <h1 class="inline-header">Example.</h1>
  <h1 id="sliding-text" class="inline-header">slide</h1>
</div>
<button id="slideButton">SLIDE</button>
```

I tried other solutions I found through searching, but they don't seem to work. For ex, giving the outside container a fixed height with overflow hidden, will prevent the slide from pushing outside elements down, but pushes the left (static) text upwards as the right side goes down. Here is a JSFiddle showing what happens in my orig code.

https://jsfiddle.net/9hj6y79k/11/

Essentially I just want the right side to slide out without moving anything else.

I would like the position to stay as relative (rather than switching it all to absolute positioning), but if switching to absolute is the best way to do it I would not be opposed. Could anybody help out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add overflow:hidden; in css

https://jsfiddle.net/9hj6y79k/12/

```
.inline-header {
  display: inline-block;overflow:hidden;
}

#title-container {
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your css class to this:

```
 .inline-header {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9hj6y79k/13/